# The following cosine series

Tags: sequences-and-series

To find the summation of the series  which is the function f(n) defined as:

$$ f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \cos(kx).$$

I tried to solve it. But I am getting a second order differential equation for $f(n)$.

Is there some other way?

Comment: Is this $n^2\cos (nx)$ or $n^{2\cos (nx)}$?

Comment: its n^2 cos(nx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just exploit:
$$ f(n) = \text{Re}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 e^{ikx}\right) $$
and:
$$ (1-x)^3 \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 x^k = x+x^2-(n^2+2n+1)x^{1+n}+(2n^2+2n-1)x^{2+n}-n^2 x^{3+n}. $$